# QGIS raster tool closing on parameter input

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I'm trying to run the Merge tool on some rasters using QGIS 3.8.3 on a 64 bit Mac and when I add the layers as inputs, the tool just automatically closes (every time), no matter which parameters I'm checking or unchecking.  It doesn't show an error, it doesn't try to run the tool, the window just vanishes.  It doesn't matter if I load from the layers in the layers panel or add them from files.  As soon as I hit ok to add the input layers, the window is just gone.

Has anyone run into this behavior before and know a fix?

Comment: I can confirm 3.8.3 works for me on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with the raster tool closing in QGIS 3.8 Mac. The window disappears as soon as input layers are selected. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Same issue here with QGIS 3.10.1 (development version)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 3.10 and the window seemed like it was disappearing, but it was actually just jumping behind the main window.